# Need GPIO access NOT using Raspberry Pi with 22.04 LTS with proper permissions not sudo

Tags: sudo, adduser

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an industrial computer **not** RasPi with a complex Python program that requires access to GPIO pins at a location 0x0B20.  This works well using sudo and portio.iopl(3) to elevate user status within my program.  But things get convoluted when I want to introduce other system level events like playsound, etc.  I've seen discussions on the raspi forums which talk about adding user name to gpio groups and wondering if there's a generic parallel for other computer systems running Ubuntu because no everything is a Pi !
Also, I rather not have to deal with environment variables and going in/out of sudo, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the hardware that you reference that isn't a Raspberry Pi. Thanks